# How do i convert the following to MON-FRI using Java code

Tags: java

```
<Days>
    <day>Mon</day>
     <day>Tue</day>
     <day>Wed</day>
     <day>Thu</day>
     <day>Fri</day>
</Days>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Assuming that this is in XML form, what how do you wish to "convert the following to MON-FRI"?

Comment: i want to convert to days which can retrieve the complete days for example in cron expression we have like "0 0 13 ? * MON-FRI *"

Comment: For this format i want to convert it to MON-FRI

Comment: explain in detail else this question is heading to close.

Comment: Am i understanding it correctly that you would like to convert a list of days into a range? so if you had Mon, Tue, Wed, you would like to convert it to MON-WED?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  File file = new File("YourXMLFile.xml");
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = db.parse(file);
  doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
  NodeList nodeLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("days");

  if (nodeLst.getLenth() > 1) {
     String first = ((Node) nodeLst.item(s)).getNodeValue().toString().toUpperCase();
     String last = ((Node) nodeLst.item(nodeLst.getLength() - 1)).getNodeValue().toString().toUpperCase();
     System.out.println(first + "-" + last);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go an example using xstream library:

```
package MonFri.monfri;

import java.util.List;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.DomDriver;


public class App 
{
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xstream.alias("day", String.class);
    xstream.alias("Days", List.class);
    List<String> days = (List<String>)xstream.fromXML(data);
    String firstDay = days.get(0);
    String lastDay = days.get(days.size()-1);
    System.out.println(firstDay.toUpperCase() + "-" + lastDay.toUpperCase());
}
private static String data = "<Days>\n" + 
        "    <day>Mon</day>\n" + 
        "     <day>Tue</day>\n" + 
        "     <day>Wed</day>\n" + 
        "     <day>Thu</day>\n" + 
        "     <day>Fri</day>\n" + 
        "</Days>";
}
```

which prints MON-FRI

Hope it helps